# java nio client server return wrong value to client

Tags: java, nio

I have created a client-server application using java nio which is working fine but my problem is that when the server has many clients connected to the server responds to the wrong client other than the requesting client For example if client A request information of person one the server returns information of person one to client B instead of client A. I have tried synchronizing the objects but still doesn't work fine what could be the problem.
Here is my sample code for the server

```
ByteArrayInputStream ins = new ByteArrayInputStream(bb.array());
ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(ins);
List l;
synchronized (ois) {
    l = (List) ois.readObject();
}

ois.close();
bb.clear();

Thread t = new Thread(new TransmitData(l, this.sc, ss));
t.start();
```

Comment: I think, at least we need to see the part of the servercode which is responsible for the communication with the clients. Better would be a complete example which produces the unwanted behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

```
bb.array()
```

returns the entire array. You should use

```
bb.array(), bb.position(), bb.limit()
```

as the constructor arguments, or

```
bb.array(), 0, bb.position()
```

if you've flipped it.

NB You don't need to synchronize on a method-local object. Nobody else can even see it.